# In and Double to string

Tags: string, methods, int, switch-statement, double

Given skeleton program and I cannot figure out how this works...

Must use this format...

Cannot get it to read arguments from argument lines and do not know how to use the switch to go to different methods...

```
Program:
        //**********************************************************************************
    //Purpose:  Compute personal income taxes.
    //
    //Input:    Name, status, and annual income
    //
    //Output:   name, status, annual income, and tax due
    //
    //    Expand and complete the documentation section
    //
    //**********************************************************************************
    public class MyIncomeTax5{
   //Declarations
   public static String name;
   public static String status;
   public static double statusName;
   public static double annualIncome;
   public static double taxDue;

   //*******************************************************************************
   // Have a documentation section in front of each method
   //
   //*******************************************************************************
   public static void main (String [] args){
      readArguments(args);
      computeTax();
      //printOutput();
   }

   public static void readArguments(String [] args){

      //Assign arguments to name, status, and annual income
      /*System.out.println ("readArguments to be implemented");
      System.out.println ("in readArguments assign arguments to name, status, and annual income");*/
      name = args[0];
      status = args[1];
      //annualIncome = args[2];

   }

   public static void computeTax(){

      //Use a switch statement to invoke the appropriate method
      //Based on the value in status and assign a value to statusName.

      switch (status){
      case "0": computeSingleFilers();

               break;
      case "1":

               break;
      case "2":

               break;
      case "3":

               break;
      default: 
      }


  }

  public static void computeSingleFilers(){ 

  }

  public static void computeMarriedFilingJointly(){

  }

   public static void computeMarriedFilingSeparately(){

  }

  public static void computeHeadOfHousehold(){

  }

  /*public static void printOutput(){

   displayHeader();
   displayFooter();
  }

   public static void displayHeader(){
   System.out.println ("********************************************************************");
   System.out.println ("**                                                                **");
   System.out.println ("**        Estimating 2016 Personal Federal Income Tax             **");
   System.out.println ("**                                                                **");
   System.out.println ("**        CS1301                                                  **");
   System.out.println ("**                                                                **");
   System.out.println ("**        2/10/2017                                               **");
   System.out.println ("**                                                                **");
   System.out.println ("********************************************************************");
   System.out.printf ("%-25s%-25s", "Name:", name);
   System.out.printf ("%-25s%-25s", "Status:", statusName);
   System.out.printf ("%-25s%-25s", "Name:", name);
   System.out.printf ("%-28s%-25s", "Annual Income:", annualIncome);
   System.out.printf ("%-28s%-25s", "2016 estimated tax due:", taxDue);



   }

    public static void displayFooter(){
    System.out.println ("********************************************************************");
    System.out.println ("**                                                                **");
    System.out.println ("**        It is needed but not fun to pay taxes                   **");
    System.out.println ("**                                                                **");
    System.out.println ("**        Have a good day                                         **");
    System.out.println ("**                                                                **");
    System.out.println ("********************************************************************");
    */




    }
```

Comment: Everything works except getting the double from the arguments line, must remain a number for calculations....

Answer (score 0):

**your declaration should be:**

```
   //Declarations
   public static String name;
   public static int status;
   public static double statusName;
   public static double annualIncome;
   public static double taxDue;
```

**parse it like this:**

```
    public static void readArguments(String [] args){
       name = args[0];
       status = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
       annualIncome = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
   }
```

and then change your switch statement cases to `int` by removing its double quotation marks.

```
cases "0":
```

to

```
cases 0:
```

`args[1]` and `args[2]` is literally came from an Array of `String[]`, so it is actually returning a **String value**, so you need to parse it in order to convert it's type of data, see code above how I parse **String to int and double.**

Comment: I cannot change this, this is apart of the skeleton I was given... I cannot figure how to make it run, I am using jgrasp and have to run arguments through the run arguments line, and would the same need to be done to annualIncome, keeping in mind I need this to remain a double in order to do math later on, also how would I use the switch to go to the differnt methods. Thanks in advanced

Comment: MyIncomeTax5.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
   public static String status = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable args
  location: class MyIncomeTax5
MyIncomeTax5.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
   public static double annualIncome = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
                                                          ^

Comment: Updated program above

Comment: I have everything working until i get to the double, I changed it to what you suggested and got this error

Comment: MyIncomeTax5.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
   public static double annualIncome = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
                                                          ^
  symbol:   variable args
  location: class MyIncomeTax5
1 error

Comment: Check my Updated Answer. you should parse it inside the method `readArguments()`. not in the Instance variable.